# Tables and storage issues

Tags: smart-contract

Am I right to say that the data stored in a contract are stored as tables and that for every row, we would have to emplace that row to a user, who would then pay for the storage?

Or is one particular user liable for the storage of the whole smart contract?

Comment: each row need a biller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, someone has to pay for the table store, i.e. RAM. You (contract) can choose who to pay. For example, in eosio.token contract, it is the "sender" paying RAM if the receiver is not in the balance table.

Comment: what about every entry in the table, can i bill them to each user specifically?? Or the person that owns the contract pays for everything

Comment: yes, you can bill different accounts for different rows. like `eosio.token` bills different accounts for storing their own balance

Comment: Which line of code specifies who pays for storage and CPU?

Comment: Ah found it the multi index methods have a payer argument :)